# Why does New <Type> With {} work but New With {} doesn't?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, anonymous-types, razor-2

I've always used `New With {}` with no issues. Why is this different?

**Razor VB.NET code**

```
Using Ajax.BeginForm(New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "Post"})
    @* no problem *@
End Using
```

```
Using Ajax.BeginForm(New With {.HttpMethod = "Post"})
    @* Value of type '<anonymous type>' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions'. *@
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) (`New With {}`) does not extend/inherit `AjaxOptions` - and an object conforming to `AjaxOptions` is *required* by `BeginForm`.